# Put image objects side by side in Rmarkdown

Tags: r, r-markdown

Is there a way I can put two image objects side by side in Rmarkdown (html output)?

Ideally, I would like to be able to do something like this:

````
```{r}
library(ggplot2)
library(data.table)

dt<-data.table(a=1:10, b=1:10)
gg <- ggplot(dt,aes(a,b)) + geom_line()
```
````

And then call `gg` twice (or w/ another object) either in another code chunk or inline like (though this doesn't work)

```
`r gg` `r gg`
```

And have them appear in the html side by side. I haven't seen anything specific to Rmarkdown and only some other suggestions for saved images rather than an object like I have shown here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is how I arrange three plots

```
library(ggplot2)
library(gridExtra)

o1 <- ggplot(...)

o2 <- ggplot(...)

o3 <- ggplot(...)

# for Aligning Axes in ggplot2 see 
# http://www.exegetic.biz/blog/2015/05/r-recipe-aligning-axes-in-ggplot2/

o2 <- ggplot_gtable(ggplot_build(o2))
o3 <- ggplot_gtable(ggplot_build(o3))
maxWidth = unit.pmax(o2$widths[2:3], o3$widths[2:3])

o2$widths[2:3] <- maxWidth
o3$widths[2:3] <- maxWidth

grid.arrange(o1, arrangeGrob(o2, o3, nrow=2),
             ncol=2, widths=c(1, 2))
```

The result is something like this

[image]

Comment: That works great, thanks. Do you know if there is any way to do something similar with an html widget in R? Like one from the `dygraphs` package? It says only `grobs` are allowed.